# No mysql database in mysql server - how do I give users permissions?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a mysql server (5.5.44) running on my local Ubuntu 14 machine.
I can start the interactive shell via

```
$ mysql
```

When I ask to see all the databases, there is only one

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
```

If I try to make a new database I get an error

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE purchases;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'danielsank'@'localhost' to database 'purchases'
```

I am puzzled by how to resolve this problem.
I'm used to mysql servers always having a database called `mysql` containing user access data: passwords, allowed hosts, etc.
My server installation doesn't seem to have this.

How do I give myself permission to create new tables, given that there is no `mysql` database in the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that I am invoking mysql as user `danielsank`, but that user does not have privileges to make new tables, nor to see the `mysql` database!

The issue becomes clear by invoking mysql as root

```
$ mysql -u root

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

Now we can see the `mysql` database, and we can check it for user information

```
mysql> USE DATABASE mysql;
mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM user;
+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| User             | Host                    | Password                    |
+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| root             | localhost               |                             |
| root             | <my machine name>       |                             |
| root             | 127.0.0.1               |                             |
| root             | ::1                     |                             |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost               | *<a really long string>     |
| danielsank       | localhost               |                             |
+------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

We can create the new database

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE purchases;
```

and grant permissions to danielsank

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON purchases . * TO 'danielsank'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Although this mistake addressed by this answer is fairly elementary, I posted a question-answer because elsewhere on the internet people are advocating "fixing" this problem by nuking all of the permissions and starting over.